How to connect to Clickhouse with SSL-on in Python?
I trying connect to Clickhouse database in Python with pandahouse .
In Dbeaver my connection settings:
host: **.***.**.***
port: 8443
database: db_name
user: user_name
password: ***
SSH: off
SSL: on
SSl mode: None

How to add SSL - setting to pandahouse connection?
I've also tryed clickhouse_connect, but don't get how to add SSL to connection.

So instead of http use https? What have you tried? What research did you do?

It's don't work. This connection setting is only one working option to connect my database.

What "didn't work" exactly? In what way? What have you tried exactly? Please post your code. Please the output that you are seeing.

You certainly should be able to get clickhouse_connect to work if your ClickHouse server is correctly configured.  The code should be as simple as:
import clickhouse_connect
client = clickhouse_connect.get_client(host='xx.xx.xx.xx', port=8443, secure=True, verify=False)
Your problem might be that your ClickHouse SSL certificate uses a hostname, not an IP address (which is why verify=False could work).

I figure out, how to make this connection.
At least it's work in my case.
import clickhouse_connect
connect = clickhouse_connect.get_client(
    interface='https'
    , host = '*.*.*.*'
    , port = 8443
    , database = 'database_name'
    , username = 'user'
    , password = 'password'
    , secure = 'https'
    , verify = 'True'
    , server_host_name = 'database_host_name.com'
    )


Glad you got it working.  To simplify it a bit you can skip the secure and verify arguments.  secure is automatically set to True if interface https is specified, and verify defaults to True as well.
